# Create BlobContainerClient from Azure SAS URI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

In the Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob library you could create a blob upload client using a SAS URI.

```
var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobSasUri);
```

However, this library has been deprecated in favor of Azure.Storage.Blobs. I am unsure how to create an instance of BlobContainerClient using a SAS URI since none of the class's constructors allow for a URI parameter. Is this even possible? Or do I need to just use an HttpClient to call the Blob service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the library `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, you can create the `BlobContainerClient` instance by using this constructor:

`public BlobContainerClient(Uri blobContainerUri, BlobClientOptions options = null);`

For example, you have a `container sas uri` like below:

```
"https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer111?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-10-27T08:45:57Z&st=2020-10-27T00:45:57Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxx";
```

Then you can use the code below to create `BlobContainerClient` instance:

```
        string sasuri = "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer111?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-10-27T08:45:57Z&st=2020-10-27T00:45:57Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxx";
        Uri container_uri = new Uri(sasuri);
        var container_client = new BlobContainerClient(container_uri);

        //other code
```

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, it seems that it has been deprecated in favor of Azure.Storage.Blobs.

You need to create get a reference to the `CloudBlobContainer` from the container where you want to upload to:

```
var connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}",
    storageAccountName, // your storage account name
    accessKey); // your storage account access key

var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("my-container");
```

Specify and retrieve the sas URI

```
SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30);
sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create;

var sasUri = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);
```

Upload files:

```
var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(sasUri));
await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(@"c:\myfile.txt");
```

More details at this [link](https://markheath.net/post/upload-azure-blob-storage-sas)

Comment: Isn't CloudBlockBlob part of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob?

Comment: Yes, it is part of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob